# Increment an Array Twice By Accident?

Tags: java, arrays

new student trying to learn java here. Got a problem about arrays that I haven't been able to work for the life of me. The ultimate goal of the problem is to output a one-dimensional array of integers (the size of which will be designated by the user), and the numbers to be changed into asterisks.

So for example the output should look like:

China **** 
Cuba ** (as a new line)
Guam ***** (as a new line)

The string names are stored in a separate array as well.

Here is what I had:

```
String[] countryList = new String[country];
int[] numVisits = new int[country];

System.out.println("Here is another look of your data:");
    StringBuilder asteriskConvert = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < countryList.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.println(countryList[index] + " " + asteriskConvert.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisits[index]; ++i)
        {
            asteriskConvert.append("*");
        }
    }
```

I know the issue has to do with the increments. It's adding the numbers of the first data set with the 2nd one and so on. I'm not quite sure how to fix it, and I been pulling my hair out over it.

Any guidance would be much appreciated! THANKS!

**This is what you see with the program:**
How many countries have you visited?: 2
Enter the 2 countries you have visited:
China
Cuba
Now enter the number of times you have visited each country:
2
3
Here is another look of your data:

China **
Cuba *****     ---THIS IS THE ISSUE - it's adding the above number

Wow you traveled alot!

Comment: I cannot see you incrememting anything more than once. You'll have to be more specific. What is the expected result? What do you see instead?

Comment: You append the `*` to the string builder so the list of `*` grows continually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not re-initializing the `asteriskConvert` StringBuilder so it keeps growing. Reset it inside the loop for each country to get a new count.

The print statement also needs to move to after the innerloop because we are reseting the StringBuilder beforehand.

```
String[] countryList = new String[country];
int[] numVisits = new int[country];

System.out.println("Here is another look of your data:");
    StringBuilder asteriskConvert;
    for (int index = 0; index < countryList.length; index++)
    {
        asteriskConvert = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisits[index]; i++)
        {
            asteriskConvert.append("*");
        }
        System.out.println(countryList[index] + " " + asteriskConvert.toString());
    }
```

Should result in:

> China **
>
> Cuba ***

The result is still:

> **
>
> China ***
>
> Cuba

That means:

```
"".equals(countryList[0])
"China".equals(countryList[1])
"Cuba".equals(countryList[2])

numVisits[0] == 2
numVisits[1] == 3
numVisits[2] == 0
```

Comment: Yea - sorry Harry, but I'm not sure if that's right. I get an output in a way that puts a line of asterisks above a string.

Comment: Yea it's outputting: like this ***(one line) Country **** (one line) country (one line). The asterisks are up one more line then they should be.

Comment: i also moved the output statement to after the numVisits loop. did you catch that?

Comment: I thought it had to do with the way the array and appended string are incremented. I tried moving the order around and got similar results.

Comment: Yea, I saw that. The output statement doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Try copying and pasting the above code and check the output.

Comment: based on your edit it is probably the arrays which i assumed where correct in the first place - see my edit

Comment: Ah dang, your right. My arrays were out of sync. I honestly didn't think that was the issue :( THANKS SO MUCH!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Try** this:

```
String[] countryList = new String[country];
int[] numVisits = new int[country];

System.out.println("Here is another look of your data:");

for (int index = 0; index < countryList.length; index++){
    StringBuilder asteriskConvert = new StringBuilder();       
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisits[index]; ++i){
            asteriskConvert.append("*");
        }
    System.out.println(countryList[index] + " " + asteriskConvert.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but the output was the same as Harry's above. A line of asterisks is being placed above a string. And one string has no asterisks next to it. It should be like what I edited above. Thanks again though.